# I got a wrong result when i want to update user status(online/offline) when the user connect or disconnect to the server with socket io

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, vue.js, express

*the wrong is that the updated user in MongoDB is not the right one, because the altered user is the last one connected or disconnected to the server ,
here is the server side.*

> **routes/socket.js**

```
      module.exports = function (io) {
      var array_of_connection = [];
      let senderTokent;
      const userIds = [];
    
      io.sockets.use(function (socket, next) {
        if (socket.handshake.query && socket.handshake.query.token) {
          jwt.verify(socket.handshake.query.token, "lol", function (err, decoded) {
            if (err) return next(new Error("Authentication error"));
            senderToken = decoded;
            next();
          });
        } else {
          next(new Error("Authentication error"));
        }
      }).on("connection", async function  (socket) {
        socket._id = senderToken.user._id;
        if (!userIds.includes(senderToken.user._id)) {
          userIds.push(senderToken.user._id);
          array_of_connection.push(socket);
        } else {
          console.log('user already opened socket');
        }
        
        const user = await db.userSchema.findOneAndUpdate({_id: senderToken.user._id}, {$set:{online: true}}, {new: true})
        for (let i = 0; i < array_of_connection.length ; i++) {
          if (array_of_connection[i]._id !== senderToken.user._id) {
           array_of_connection[i].emit('online-users', user._id);
          }
        }
       socket.on('disconnect', async () => {
      const userIndex = userIds.indexOf(senderToken.user._id);
      userIds.splice(userIndex, 1);
      const socketIndex = array_of_connection.indexOf(socket);
      array_of_connection.splice(socketIndex, 1);
        const user = await db.userSchema.findOneAndUpdate({_id: senderToken.user._id}, {$set:{online: false}}, {new: true})
        for (let i = 0; i < array_of_connection.length; i++) {
          if (array_of_connection[i]._id !== senderToken.user._id) {
            array_of_connection[i].emit('friend-leave2', senderToken.user._id)
          }
        }
  });
});
```

Comment: i'm using vue.js as a front end

Comment: i found the mistake, i replaced (senderToken.user._id) with (socket._id)